# NetCore command line build handling for bait and switch

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

So I've got a project with the following structure:

`syntax: Project (Assembly Name)
- P1 (Assembly-1)
- P2.A (Assembly-2)
- P2.B (Assembly-2)
- P3 (Assembly-3)`

The point of which was to facilitate bait and switch where P2.A and P2.B both have the same assembly name.

Proj dependency is such that P3 is a dependency of everything else. P1 is a net standard project which depends on P2.A (the bait) and the assembly gets swapped with P2.B on respective platforms as expected

Now in the unit test project, within this solution where I'm not depending on a nuget package but directly on the projects, I have a UnitTest project depending on P1, P2.B, P3.

When I compile this in visual studio it works as expected(even this part seems risky as to how the assembly from P2.B was the last one transferred to output folder and not P2.A which P1 depends on, but for whatever reason this works). However if I try to just do a `dotnet build` from command line, it fails along the lines of `error : Cannot find project info for '**\P2.A.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference.` I'm guessing somewhere the Assembly name being the same between project P2.A and P2.B screws things up, not sure how to workaround this.

If I just remove the unit test project from directly depending on P2.B it works fine from the command line too however then we're only left with the bait dll.

Not sure why the behaviour is different from visual studio and command line.

I've also tried to resolve this by removing the direct dependency to P2.B and instead setup a msbuild Target for AfterTargets="Build" to trigger the build of P2.B and supply the output path accordingly to that as the unit test project output folder. This kinda works where the switch does occur and `dotnet build/test` works fine. however building with a specified runtime then fails `error : Assets file '**\P2.B\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETStandard,Version=v1.2/win10-x64'` which ofc works just ok if I removed the custom MSBuild Target for after build targeting P2.B

Any pointers to get this resolved would be very helpful.

Thanks

If it helps I'm using Visual Studio 2017(15.4.1) dotnet sdk (2.0.2)

Comment: I have create a sample but could not reproduce this issue, not sure if I did something wrong. Would you mind share us a simple test sample so that we could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Judy soz I missed this. I actually had the second issue resolved so just went via that route as I've mention in the answer. Thanks for offering to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else runs into a similar issue for bait and switch, got the second issue(`custom target for after build but issue with building with a specified runtime then fails`) resolved. That error seemed to be cos of a missing `Restore` target build trigger.

So to get this to be functional:

- I removed the "switch" lib(P2.B) from being a direct project reference dependency of the unit test project
- Added the following as a custom target

In net core unit test project .csproj

```
<Target Name="BaitAndSwitchTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LinkedProject>..\P2.B\P2.B.csproj</LinkedProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuild Condition="'$(LinkedProject)' != '' " Projects="$(LinkedProject)" Targets="Restore" />
  <MSBuild Condition="'$(LinkedProject)' != '' " Projects="$(LinkedProject)" Targets="Build" Properties="OutputPath=..\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

this then essentially builds the switch target as an after build step and places it in the output folder of the unit test project and looks like `dotnet build/test/...` works just fine from CLI.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.